# BIRT report label at pixel-precise position

Tags: report, label, birt, grid-layout, pixel-perfect

I am developing BIRT report.

The report is required to have text-label at pixel-precised position (X at x pixel, Y at y pixel).

It is possible to do it Actuate report.
But it looks like BIRT use grid-layout, which is not possible to specify precise pixel for a report components.

Any samples, ideas, suggestions would greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If it's not dynamic, you can add the item on the Master Page and specify the margin (note that the master page itself will probably have margins set already, so you might have to do some substraction to get the right figure).

Comment: Thanks. 
It is not dynamic. It is static.
But it supposed to appear only on one page so masterpage is not a perfect place.

Any other suggestions than masterpage?
Does BIRT support precision of position in body?

Comment: It's completely understandable to think of the master page in terms of 'what you use for multiple pages', but that's not the entire story. You could say the master page is the 'priority' page, which elements have precedence over whatever happens in the body (this is handwavey, but it's the general idea). The body is set up to be dynamic. So the master page would be the place to do this even if you use only a single page. I agree that it's not ideal!

Comment: Thanks. I got your points.
I managed to achieved the same effect when setting margin to the text-label. Making it standing alone, not in any grid.
It is not ideal neither.